# MySQL error message not ignored with -f option

Tags: mysql

i using -f or --force in mysql import but error alway not ignore.

> mysql -f -u user -p db_story < story.sql

error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 13639: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\r\n              To&#xE0;n th&#xE2;n kh&#xF4;ng c&#xF3; n&#x1EED;a ph&#x1EA7;n s&#x1EE9;' at line 1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the code at that line in `story.sql`?

Comment: Hi @grizzly  create, insert data in sql file

Comment: Is that exactly what it says? That's incorrect SQL if that's what it says. Would you mind posting some lines around that code in your question?

Comment: my database file is 13 Gb, may be incorrect file when i upload via ftp to server, i see it 10Gb in server, so i try upload again, and import sql worked. Thank for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You likely have an error in your SQL file.